# Entity Id validation

Tags: symfony, validation

I am writing REST API, where resources are entities. There is a problem with Id field, which has NoBlank and NotNull constraints (which are logical) when creating new entity - obviously a new entity has no Id before writing to DB. However validation component of course says the entity is not valid. How to overcome this issue without removing the constraints from the Id field?

Comment: Are we talking about auto-increment integer IDs, pre-insert determined UUID or something in-between? At what moment of time do your entities acquire IDs?

Comment: Incremental in this case, but really it doesn't matter. I am using forms and getting JSON sent through the API. When I have JSON with entity data, I need to validate (through standard forms component) entity. But because entity has no id at this stage of course, hence the validation error.

Comment: I don't think it makes much sense to validate the auto-generated id. But you could always persist, and use the validator service manually afterwards.

Comment: @Yoshi ok. But I can not validate before persisting, because I need to check whether the entity is correct before it goes to DB.

Comment: You see, how you're going in circles here? But if you must, you always would have an id to delete by. But again, an auto-generated id is nothing to validate. If that assignment would fail, something system-relevant, from which you probably won't recover anyway, failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion you shouldn't have a constraint on your id.

Url of create should be `[POST]/resource` and url of edit should be `[PUT]/resource/{id}`.
(Or POST/PATCH depending on how strictly you are doing rest HTTP methods)

THis way the id is always mandatory.

If you don't want this routing logic, you can use [validation groups](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html)

```
/**
 * @Assert\NotNull(groups={"create"})
 */
private $id;
/**
 * @Assert\NotNull(groups={"create","edit"})
 */
private $whatever;
```

Comment: Ok, this seems to be the solution. I am not REST purist, and in fact I am wondering about leaving only POST for create/update (if the JSON contains Id, it is an update). Or it would be too over simplicitized then?

Comment: Honestly only having Get/Post is enough. I still prefer to have the id in the url because it is much common (so others people would understand faster your code), and you will have to expose a `[GET]/user/{id}` anyway

Comment: Do you do anything (a validation) when someone tries to send "Id" in the JSON when creating (POST) an entity?

Comment: it's better to never send the id. The client shouldn't dictate which ID he wants the ressource to be created with (he can't know this information). Either ignore the id or send a validation error. I personally never use the id inside the data